# How to avoid destructuring pattern

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've noticed I have the tendency of doing the following structure while destructuring and returning an object with the values.

```
const { isLoading, fieldValues, stage } = state.personalInformation
return {
  isLoading,
  fieldValues,
  stage,
};
```

This is fine with only three arguments but when I need to pass a lot of arguments it gets nasty really quick.

Without destructuring it feels too much verbose.

```
return {
  isLoading: state.personalInformation.isLoading,
  fieldValues: state.personalInformation.fieldValues,
  stage: state.personalInformation.stage,
};
```

Is there a way to avoid this pattern?

Comment: why can't you just return `state.personalInformation`

Comment: there're some fields inside personalInformation that I don't want to return

Comment: @Ionthas Why not let the caller care about which fields to use?

Comment: _"This is fine with only three arguments but when I need to pass a lot of arguments"_ What would be the alternative, where multiple distinct properties of an object, but not all properties of the object, are referenced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to avoid repeating the property names, right now the only way to do that is to give yourself a reusable helper function, something along the lines of:

```
function grab(obj, ...props) {
  const result = {};
  props.forEach(prop => result[prop] = obj[prop]);
  return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
return grab(state.personalInformation, "isLoading", "fieldValues", "stage");
```

Example:

```js
var state = {
  personalInformation: {
    isLoading: true,
    fieldValues: "bar",
    stage: 14,
    other: "something"
  }
};
function grab(obj, ...props) {
  const result = {};
  props.forEach(prop => result[prop] = obj[prop]);
  return result;
}
function foo() {
  return grab(state.personalInformation, "isLoading", "fieldValues", "stage");
}
console.log(foo());
```

(But there are 18 different ways to spin that `grab` function, that's just one approach.)

You could also have a `grabAllBut` which copies all properties *except* the ones you list, for when that's the better option...